# Geolocation of a drawn point on printed map without scanning

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, georeferencing

I have a printed map of a district with several points on it that can be used as geolocation reference points.

I have the shapefile of this map in QGIS.
If someone draws a point on the printed map, how can I find the position of the drawn point without scanning the printed map ?

I was thinking of measuring the distance from that point to three other points on the paper, so I can have the zoom used and find the position. Is there a plugin to help with that? Are there other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: This is essentially a math problem. See this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/100456 you could probably do something in Python to solve this.

Comment: Thanks. If I take the formulas in this answer, can I replace x,y with latitude and longitude or is there a transformation to make using the projection ? Considering that it is the map of a district it is at an important level of zoom and I need a precision at around 50m.

Comment: you should be able to plug in your latitude and longitude. Keep in mind latitude is Y and longitude is X so it's the reverse of how we usually think of things.